# Alternative ways to find tables with specific storage engine?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, storage-engine

I have a VPS with three accounts and 5 db's. Recently I added MySQLTuner. All of my tables are MyISAM, but the results MySQLTuner are showing that I have 14 tables that use InnoDB.

```
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 257M (Tables: 618)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 560K (Tables: 14)
```

I looked all of my databases on phpMyAdmin and I couldn't find those tables.

Is there any way to find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login as `root@localhost` and query [information_schema.tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tables-table.html) by Storage Engine

```
SELECT table_schema,table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE engine='InnoDB';
```

To locate the InnoDB tables that are belong to you, run this

```
SELECT table_schema,table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE engine='InnoDB'
AND table_schema NOT IN
('information_schema','performance_schema','mysql');
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!